# How to put arguments in structure?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, printf

hello i'm creating a xx_printf function and in a function called find_correspondence, i have too many arguments so i thought i could make a struct and just call the *struct but when i tried to call the find_correspondence in xx_printf function i'm getting a segfault! how can solve this problem.

```
int     find_correspondance(char *format, char *tab_sign, ptr_fonc *tab_func, int i, va_list ap)
{
  int           a;

  a = 0;
  while ((format[i] != tab_sign[a]) && tab_sign[a] != '\0')
      a = a + 1;
  if (tab_sign[a] == '\0')
      {
        my_putchar('%');
        my_putchar(format[i]);
      }
  else
    tab_func[a](ap);
  return (i);
}

int     my_printf(char *format, ...)
{
  va_list       ap;
  ptr_fonc      *func_tab;
  char          *flag_tab;
  int           i;

  va_start(ap, format);
  func_tab = tab_func(func_tab);
  flag_tab = tab_sign(flag_tab);
  i = 0;
  while(format[i] != '\0')
    {
      if (format[i] == '%')
        {
          i += 1;
          if (format[i] == '%')
            my_putchar('%');
          else if (format[i] == '\0')
            return ;
          else
            **find_correspondence(format, flag_tab, func_tab, i, ap);**
        }
      else
        my_putchar(format[i]);
      i++;
    }
  va_end(ap);
}
```

**find_correspondence(format, flag_tab, func_tab, i, ap);**
any help?

Comment: Please sort out the indentation and use of braces. May help

Comment: I can't see that you're actually using a struct anywhere at all here, though (unless it's the `va_list` you're referring to). Also, please point out the actual line where it crashes.

Comment: I don't understand how a printf like function would take a set of args that would correspond to a structure. Don't use va_list, pass a pointer to a structure. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be you missed a "struct" right before your structure name va_list in the arguments list. It should look like the followd:

```
find_correspondance(char *format, char *tab_sign, ptr_fonc *tab_func,
                            int i, ***struct***   va_list ap)
```

And also, here is a small program might be used as a precedent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct namect{
   char fname[20];
   char lanme[20];
   int letters;
};

struct namect getinfo(void);
struct namect makeinfo(struct namect);
void showinfo(struct namect);

int main(void){
   struct namect person;
   person=getinfo();
   person=makeinfo(person);
   showinfo(person);

   getchar();
   return 0;
}

struct namect getinfo(void)
{
   struct namect temp;
   printf("Please enter your first name.\n");
   gets(temp.fname);
   printf("Please enter your last name.\n");
   gets(temp.lanme);
   return temp;
}

struct namect makeinfo(struct namect info)
{
   info.letters=strlen(info.fname)+strlen(info.lanme);
   return info;
}

void showinfo(struct namect info)
{
   printf("%s %s,your name contains %d letters.\n",info.fname,info.lanme,info.letters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some implementations of va_arg...

What might be happening is that you should be doing a va_start each time around the loop. 
If you are using va_arg in the tab_funca; call, the args will be all read, and on the next time round the loop not what they were the first time, i.e garbage.